# Calculate Minutes to Read in SQL Function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a Trigger Function in Postgres that calculates minutes to read from my `content` field on insert.

Here is the JS Version I want to translate:

```
export function minutesToRead(data: string): string {
    const wordCount = data.trim().split(/\s+/g).length;
    return (wordCount / 100 + 1).toFixed(0);
}
```

Can this be done in pure SQL?

I have a `posts.content` field, and I would like to automatically add the minutes on an insert to `posts.minutes` field.

Here is what I have so far:

```sql
-- function

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_minutes()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  old.content -- what to do here with my content to get minutes?

  new.minutes = -- calculation result here
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;

-- triggers

CREATE TRIGGER posts_insert_minutes
BEFORE UPDATE ON posts
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_minutes();

CREATE TRIGGER posts_insert_minutes
BEFORE INSERT ON posts
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_minutes();
```

Thanks,

J

Comment: Why only calculate on an update? What about on insert? If the `minutes` column is always a calculated value based only on columns in the current row , then use a generated column instead of a trigger.

Comment: True (I added it above), still need to know how to calculate it though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following adds a generated column, `minutes_to_read`, with the same value as produced by the JS function listed in the original post:

```
ALTER TABLE posts
  ADD COLUMN minutes_to_read INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (REGEXP_COUNT(content, '[^\s]+') / 100 + 1) STORED;
```

If the column is changed to a non-integer type, then change 100 to 100.0 to allow fractional math.

Comment: There is an extra `(` at the beginning, but other than that, perfect! Thanks!

Comment: One should paste from working code instead of editing manually! I've removed the extra `(`.